# Reusable socket

Tags: php, sockets, reusability

I tryed to create a socket in php and reuse it from other process.
I know this can be done with a daemon script but I want to do this without.

I created a socket and binded it to a specific port.

```
$sock = socket_create (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);  
socket_set_option ($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1); 
socket_bind ($sock, 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 10000);
socket_connect ($sock, $host, $port);
```

And from another php file I did the same thing. But the packets that I send from the 2 file are not "validated" by host. I sniffed all ports and I see that it uses same local and destination port. I don't understand where is the problem.

Can you help me with this?
It's ok in any other programming language, or any other solution for this.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Sockets are not symmetrical. The server side listens on a specific port for a client to conect - the client does not specify the local port - only the remote port and address. Its nothing to do with the language you implement it in.

There's a very good socket server implementation available at http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/5758.html with examples.

C.

Answer (score -1):

You can't really use persistent sockets in php. When you execute a php file, a new process is created which cannot access the variables - or sockets - of a different php process so it won't know if there already exists a socket and just creates it.

Comment: Ok, but any other sollutions?

Comment: What about long term process, for example, for parsing? You CAN use persistent sockets in PHP.

Comment: @mmoreram The point still stands; one process executes one script. And if two scripts run in independent processes, they don't know about each other unless you have some form of interprocess communication. The fact that you _can_ have long term processes is irrelevant if that's not supported by your hosting model.